# After compiling my Ruby script into an exe using Ocra, running the exe still shows output consoles

Tags: ruby, windows, ocra

So I'm making a small project in Ruby, and have converted it to an exe using Ocra
The only really relevant part of the script is the following:

```
class Taskkill 
    $task_list = "config/tlist.json"

    def initialize()
        json_data = JSON.parse(File.read($task_list))
        @tasks = json_data['tasks']
    end 

    def kill()
        @tasks.each do |task|
            out,err,suc = Open3.capture3("taskkill /F /IM #{task}")
            puts "#{task} ... #{suc}"
        end
    end
end

test = Taskkill.new()
test.kill()
```

Then I converted it with Ocra, with the following command:

`ocra "c:\Users\usr\my_file_path\my_rb_script.rb" --dll ruby_builtin_dlls/libgmp-10.dll --icon ./resources/mdr256.ico --windows`

The exe is converted as expected and does what it needs to do, but when run it shows this:
[Unexpected windows keep opening until the exe has finished running.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yy2Fs.gif)

Is there any way to prevent this? I'd prefer the exe to be able to run without being disturbing to someone using the computer.

I've tried adding a few lines of code that should get rid of the window opened by the program but no success so far.

Comment: Rename the original script file to `myscript.rbw`. Double click on that in file explorer. Does it still pop open a console?

Comment: Yes, it still does open multiple consoles (that all immediately close again), just like shown in the link attached to my original post.

Comment: Open a windows terminal and run one of those commands `taskkill /F /IM ...`. Does it still briefly pop open a window like that? If so, you may be out of luck